# Adding a default role to a registered user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

There's three roles and I want to add a default "user" role whenever there's a registration. I'm using asp.net 6 mvc with identity

What I did it's not working. I checked the tables and the Identity.AspNetUsers table is updated, the Identity.Roles table is updated but the Identity.UserRoles is not getting updated

Here's the change I made in Register

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IUserStore<ApplicationUser> _userStore;
        private readonly IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser> _emailStore;
        private readonly ILogger<RegisterModel> _logger;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;

        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;

        public RegisterModel(
            UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
            IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore,
            SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager,
            ILogger<RegisterModel> logger,
            IEmailSender emailSender,
            //Added this
            RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
            _emailStore = GetEmailStore();
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
            //Added this
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = CreateUser();

                await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
                await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);

                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User created a new account with password.");


                    //Added this
                    var defaultrole = _roleManager.FindByNameAsync("User").Result;
                    //Added this
                    if (defaultrole != null)
                    {
                        IdentityResult roleresult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "User");
                    }

                    var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
                    var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
                    code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));
                    var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                        "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
                        pageHandler: null,
                        values: new { area = "Identity", userId = userId, code = code, returnUrl = returnUrl },
                        protocol: Request.Scheme);

                    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(Input.Email, "Confirm your email",
                        $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

                    if (_userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("RegisterConfirmation", new { email = Input.Email, returnUrl = returnUrl });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }

        private ApplicationUser CreateUser()
        {
            try
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance<ApplicationUser>();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Can't create an instance of '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}'. " +
                    $"Ensure that '{nameof(ApplicationUser)}' is not an abstract class and has a parameterless constructor, or alternatively " +
                    $"override the register page in /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register.cshtml");
            }
        }

        private IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser> GetEmailStore()
        {
            if (!_userManager.SupportsUserEmail)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("The default UI requires a user store with email support.");
            }
            return (IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>)_userStore;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to follow a tutorial that at some point says "Create an Enum for the supported Roles. Add a new Enum at Enums/Roles" and I have no idea where to put this. Is this supposed to be a new class? I then changed to another tutorial and I didn't use this but I would like to know anyway

```
public enum Roles
{
    Admin,
    User
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally don't use enums, instead, I use a class like this, which normally works for me:

```
 public static class UserRoles
{
    public const string Admin = "Admin";
    public const string User = "User";
}
```

I have never monitored my database to see how the data is stored, but based on your implementation, it looks like it should work, i.e something like

```
 if (await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.User))
 {
     await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.User);
 }
```

I don't know, what do you mean by "Identity.UserRoles is not getting updated"? Have you also tried writing something like this to see the results you get?

```
await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, UserRoles.Use);
```

Comment: Thank you. I'ts not working, I'm going to try your suggestion. Also, by looking at this link https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/user-management-in-aspnet-core-mvc/#seeddefaultroles , when they mention the Enum, where would you put that? I'm a beginner, this must be a dumb question but I can't figure out if they want that as a class or implemented in any existing class. Thank you

Comment: Ah, codewithmukesh has good tutorials on .NET, you can put it anywhere. Enum or a class both work fine, enum is actually the best. It is just a way to reduce magic strings in your code and, make your code more readable, and reduce errors in the process. Assume you misspelt a role, now you have just one place to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ContextSeed
{
    public static async Task SeedRolesAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        //Seed Roles
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.SuperAdmin.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.Admin.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.Moderator.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.Basic.ToString()));
    }

    public static class Enums 
    {
        public enum Roles
        {
            SuperAdmin,
            Admin,
            Moderator,
            Basic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add enum this way

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).